# Data Encryption using RSA in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, rsa

I am using RSA Encryption using [JSBN](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)

When I write following code, I am getting error - " 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.n.bitLength')" on 92th line(var m = pkcs1pad2(text,(this.n.bitLength()+7)>>3);) in rsa.js file - http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa.js

```
var rsa = new RSAKey();
var pk = "----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----\r\n"+
"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0\r\n"+
"FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/\r\n"+
"3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB\r\n"+
"----END PUBLIC KEY----";
rsa.setPublic(pk);
var data = rsa.encrypt('hello world');
```

List of files included :
jsbn.js,
prng4.js,
rng.js,
rsa.js

Comment: Is that definitely the public key format it wants? It looks to me like it wants the bare modulus and exponents in hexadecimal on separate lines, not the PKCS format.

Comment: Hi! I did successfully RSA encryption of plain text using this libs(http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) from JavaScript.
Plain text: "hello world"

Encrypted data: "3c6d52014ab57b62d0ef9611ac3249faeb939b19f95fe0d2e9e7c5f65887bc44e2f1285a6a2e4c2df873a974a65013c21b5113115fdb1c9d87d8bab3eb6c463b6210f0e5c66b1209b57f9a6510aac398f1baa3eeb04412cf38431bb8a6ee1b8dc2f152fc231fa736142d1a9bc12b621432a2efc530840a"


How I can decrypt data from command line(using rsautl) or any other way?